# How to add new rendering hint in RenderingHints.java

Tags: rendering, java, sun, rt.jar

How to add new rendering hint in RenderingHints.java or by extending it.

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b27/java/awt/RenderingHints.java